# How to set query parameters in Django and dynamically update charts

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and this is taking a lot of my time. Any help would really be appreciated.

I am using chart js to render charts in my HTML and I have a date filter in the HTML template, which I will use as a filter to display data in charts.

[image]

I have data in the backend which needs to be displayed dynamically in the front end upon selecting the date. My backend code takes 'from' and 'to' dates from the request.
How do I pass the selected date ranges as query params to the request, so that request.GET['from'] uses my start date and update my chart in the HTML with results dynamically

Answer (score 0):

*Let's say that you have this url :* `http://localhost:8000/data?from=x&to=y`

This is how you can write your view

**Function based view :**

```
def retrieve_data(request):
    from_date = request.GET.get('from', None)
    to_date = request.GET.get('to', None)

    # Use from_date and to_date as needed
```

**Class based view :**

```
class RetrieveData(APIView):

    def get(self):
        self.from_date = self.request.GET.get('from', None)
        self.from_to = self.request.GET.get('to', None)

    # In the reste of class you can access these attributs with
    # self.from_date or self.to_date
```